# Using <f:view> on the template page in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a DataTable (Primefaces 3.5, JSF 2.0) which is populated from a database. In the first column of this table, checkboxes are displayed (multiple row selection).

After selecting row(s), when a button (`<p:commandButton>`) is pressed, the selected rows are expected to be deleted from the database.

Before deleting row(s), a confirm message regarding the deletion of the selected row(s) is displayed in `<p:confirmDialog>` with two buttons *Yes* and *No* something like the following.

Test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition template="template/Template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <ui:define name="title">Test</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form id="form">
                <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="#{testManagedBean.list}"
                             selection="#{testManagedBean.selectedValues}"
                             rowKey="#{row.id}"
                             rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:5%; text-align: center;">
                        <f:facet name="footer">
---------------->           <p:commandButton actionListener="#{testManagedBean.deleteMultipleActionListener}" oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.show()" update=":form:confirmDialogDeleteMultiple" process=":form:dataTable" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-close"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:column>                    

                    <p:column headerText="Index">
                        <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="id" headerText="Id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.id}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="countryName" headerText="Description">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.description}"/>                        
                    </p:column>                    
                </p:dataTable>                

---------------><p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialogDeleteMultiple" widgetVar="confirmDeleteMultiple" appendToBody="true" message="Delete row(s)?" showEffect="true" hideEffect="true" header="Deletion of row." severity="alert" closeOnEscape="true" closable="true">
                    <p:commandButton id="confirmDeleteMultiple" value="Yes" oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.deleteMultiple}" process="@this dataTable" update="dataTable"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="declineDeleteMultiple" value="No" onclick="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()" type="button" />
                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    @EJB(mappedName="ejb/JNDI")
    private TestService testService;
    private List<Test> list;
    private List<Test>selectedValues;

    public TestManagedBean(){}

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        list=testService.getList();
    }

    public List<Test> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public List<Test> getSelectedValues() {
        return selectedValues;
    }

    public void setSelectedValues(List<Test> selectedValues) {
        this.selectedValues = selectedValues;
    }

    public void deleteMultipleActionListener(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        //Just show a warning message, when the delete button is pressed.

        for(Test test:selectedValues)
        {
            System.out.println(test.getId()+" : "+test.getDescription());
        }//Displays the list.
    }

    public void deleteMultiple(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        System.out.println("multiple");
        for(Test test:selectedValues)
        {
            System.out.println(test.getId()+" : "+test.getDescription());
        }//The list is not null and empty.
    }
}
```

When the button (indicated by an arrow in XHTML) is pressed, the `deleteMultipleActionListener()` method in the managed bean is invoked where it simply displays the list which is populated by **the selected rows** and the confirm dialog as shown in XHTML appears afterwards. (This is just to show a warning message before deletion. The loop in this method is just for the demonstration).

When the *Yes* button on the confirm dialog is pressed, the `deleteMultiple()` method is invoked which is responsible for actual deletion of rows (`actionListioner` in `<p:commandButton>` inside `<p:confirmDialog>`) and the deletion of rows should be performed but here the list of the selected rows retrieved here is empty (not null).

---

The resulting list inside the `deleteMultiple()` method is empty because of `<f:view>` on the template page. The template page is shown below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

--------->
    <f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}" encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html">
        <f:loadBundle basename="messages.ResourceBundle" var="messages"/>

        <h:head><title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title></h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="135" collapsed="false" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" gutter="6">

                <h:form>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="languages" value="#{localeBean.language}" onchange="submit();" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="English" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="hi" itemLabel="Hindi" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="leftPanel" size="225" header="Menu Item" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="true" gutter="6">

            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="2500" maxSize="2500">
                    <ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

When I remove this template from the above `Test.xhtml` page and **use this `<f:view>` tag on the `Test.xhtml` page itself**, everything works fine and the list of the selected rows inside the `deleteMultiple()` method is obtained correctly.

So, what is going wrong? Why does the list become empty when the *Yes* button is pressed, if the template page is enclosed by `<f:view>`? Is it wrong? How to accomplish this? (`<f:view>` is used for the localization of the application as it can be imagined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved when you replace the `process="@this datatable"` in your `confirmDeleteMultiple` by `process="@this"`, which makes the button component only be processed. In fact you don't need Ajax to process your datatable when you send the deletion confirmation, because values for deletion are already stored in the bean since previous step (that's **the main benefit** of the view scope).

Making your datatable to be processed in your Ajax request invokes again the `setSelectedValues` setter, so the original value is getting overriden by the new (empty) selection.

Comment: This worked correctly. Thank you very much. Though may I know why this happens only when `<f:view>` is involved?

Comment: The `datatable` can then not be found and is plain ignored. Just keep `<f:view>` in master template as you had. By the way, the `<h:head>` in template client is misplaced and the `transient` on EJB is alarming. Get rid of both.

Comment: Don't know about EJB. I also forgot to mention that you only need an `h:head`, as @BalusC says, located in the template. I commented template client's one for testing purposes. Do you mean @BalusC that when `f:view` is put in the template client `datatable` cannot be found and it works because of that?